# How to wget website with same page and content names?

Tags: wget, download, mirror

I'm trying mirror a website where it has page:

```
http://www.site.com/news
```

and contents:

```
http://www.site.com/news/36-news/news-one
http://www.site.com/news/37-news/news-two
http://www.site.com/news/38-news/another-news-here
```

This is what I'm using

```
wget -m -Dsite.com -e robots=off -r -q -R gif,png,jpg,jpeg,GIF,PNG,JPG,JPEG \
    -t 10 http://www.site.com &
```

When wget is run, it will create a HTML file with the name `news`.

I'm unable to download the contents because the file with the name `news` already exists (I'm running Ubuntu: directories cannot have same name as files)

Below is the message that appeared when running `wget` without `-q`

> www.site.com/news/36-news: Not a directory
>   www.site.com/news/36-news/news-one: Not a directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try `--no-clobber`. However, it seems to me like you'd probably be better suited with something a little more full-featured, such as [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/). Here's the manual for the command line options: http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html

You can prefix all of your directories like this:

```
httrack "http://www.site.com/news" -O /tmp/site -N "my%p/%n.%t"
```

So the full command, similar to yours, could be something like:

```
httrack "http://www.site.com/news" -O /tmp/site -N "my%p/%n.%t" --retries=10 --ext-depth=0 --robots=0 +*.gif +*.png +*.jpg +*.jpeg +*.GIF +*.PNG +*.JPG +*.JPEG
```